# Gravitational force: Is the gravitational force dependent on the nature of the medium present in between the two masses?

Tags: gravity

Is the gravitational force dependent on the nature of the medium present in
between the two masses?

Comment: related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46099/, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/86343/